# Launching powershell scripts (with parameters) from c# app

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm trying to make a simple (or so i thought) app that will make it easier to launch .ps1 scripts, so that non-powershell savvy users can use them.
Here is how its supposed to look like
[image: Powershell launcher desing]

Now, i managed to figure out one part about running scripts:

```
private string RunPowershell_1(string skripta)
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string str in PowerShell.Create().AddScript(skripta).AddCommand("Out-String").Invoke<string>())
            
            {
            
            stringBuilder.AppendLine(str);
            
            }
        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

But i would normally run scripts that require parameters, so i would like to be able to read list of parameters from the script i import, assign value to them and then run the scrip (output should go to either txtPreview or to a file).

Is there a way to do this?
If there is another (better) approach to this I'm all ears.

Comment: Like an oldfag, I'd suggest using `Process.Start` with `ProcessStartInfo`'s args set to arguments got from user

Comment: I looked into that but this method seemed simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this powershell command to get the list of parameters.

```
(get-command get-netadapter).Parameters
```

And this is how you can read its output in C#:

```
using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
    ps.AddScript("...");                      
    Collection<PSObject> output = ps.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this code can do this, but i want to be able to read parameters from any provided script, even the ones with custom parameters